# Logo replacement in screen recording

Tags: screen-casting, tracking

I'm not an editor but I'm trying to achieve a simple effect. The use-case is I want to do a screen recording of a demo of a web application, where I can then do different exports where the logo on the webpage is different for each video. The logo will move during the screen recording. What's the best way to do the screen recording, and what's the best way to replace the logo so that I can create new exports quickly and in the most automated way?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to record the presentation without the logo altogether using open broadcast, fraps or some screen recorder. You can then animate the logo in After Effects from within a precomp and simply exchange the images in the precomp to swap to another logo.

For demos of that sort you'd usually animate the whole thing though, but since you said that you're not an editor this probably isn't an option.